# Politer way of saying "Your discussion is invalid"

Tags: synonyms, politeness

Someone is criticizing my work and they are using arguments that are not correct. I have explained the reasons why their argument is not correct and I want to conclude by saying:

> because of these reasons your discussion/argument is invalid

But I feel it is a little rude. How can I frame it in a more polite way?

Comment: Is this person a superior or an equal co-worker?

Comment: Ultimately, any phrase you use to tell someone they're a friggin' idiot will come across as an insult.

Comment: @Cargill superior.

Comment: Don’t end by ***telling*** them they’re stupid.  Just point out the discrepancies and let them come that conclusion for themselves. And don’t make any absolute statements.  “I don’t think I can agree with you on that point because ...”.  You don’t need to summarize, and essentially twist the sword.

Comment: Have you made sure that you haven't got it the wrong way round (by checking with a reliable third party)?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> For the reasons above, I cannot accept your arguments as **cogent**.

Definition:

> cogent: appealing to the intellect or powers of reasoning; convincing

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cogent))

Answer (score 1):

You could say, "I'm afraid that you're arguing from a false *[premise](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/premise)*, so your conclusions are false."

> **premise**, *n.*: a principle or statement that you consider to be true, that you base other ideas and actions on